# Sql function to turn character field into number field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm importing data from one system to another.  The former keys off an alphanumeric field whereas the latter requires a numeric integer field.  I'd like to find or write a function that I can feed the alphanumeric value to and have it return a number that would be unique to the value passed in.

My first thought was to do a hash, but of course the result of any built in hashes are going to contains letters and plus it's technically possible (however unlikely) that a hash may not be unique.

My first question is whether there is anything built in to sql that I'm overlooking, and short of that I'd like to hear suggestions on the easiest way to implement such a function.

Comment: Do you need to be able to track your new key back to the original key? I suggest you simply store you alpha key as an extra field in the target system and use an identity to generate your target system key. If you are importing a lot of data, then computing a unique key from an alphanumeric code could be prohibitve performance wise. If you do want to proceed down this route, then just consider your source key as a base 36 number that needs to be converted to a base 10 number. Still nothing built in to SQL to do that for you though.

Comment: This problem is frequently faced and overcome when building data warehouses (merging different systems), and it is overcome with surrogate keys - forget about a complex conversion, just give it a new key and remember the old key for reference purposes.

Comment: Is there a particular fixed size you have in mind, e.g. at 32-bit `int`?  Using `varbinary` would let you handle an alphanumeric as binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function which will probably convert from base 10 (integer) to base 36 (alphanumeric) and back again:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/numeral-systems-and-numbers-conversion-in-sql/

You might find the resultant number is too big to be held in an integer though.

Comment: Yeah, I was sort of wondering if this would even be feasible given the size limit on an integer field.  I'll check it out tomorrow and cross my fingers :)

Comment: Otherwise use the surrogate key method mentioned - if you are doing a lot of system merging work, you will find you will gravitate towards this - it's much simpler and more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the ascii values of each character of your string and cast the result as a bigint.

Comment: I don't think that would yield a unique result. Mapped/concatenated/cast `1 1 1` would be the same as `11 1` or `111`. Since ASCII has such a limited range of characters, you might be able to get around this by assuming each alpha value always mapped to 2 digits.

Answer (score -1):

If the original data is known to be integers you can use cast:

```
SELECT CAST(varcharcol AS INT) FROM Table
```